# Capture all the output of a script to a file (from the script itself)

Tags: bash, files, string, output

I have a bash script that calls various commands and prints some output (both from the called commands themselves, such as `git pull`, and informative messages generated by the script itself such as `Operation took XX minutes`.

I'd like to capture the whole output to a file **from the script itself**: basically I'm trying to avoid the need to call `./myscript.sh | tee file.txt` for *non-relevant-here* reasons.

Basically I'd like to do something like this:

```
startCapture

git pull

echo "Text"

other-command

endCapture
```

I also require the output to be printed on my shell while the script is running.

The final goal is to:

1. run `./myscript.sh` without additional shell constructs
2. see the output on the terminal as I do now
3. obtain a file on disk with the whole output

Is this even possible?

Comment: For those that end up here from Google, you might also consider this answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164017/103505) to just put all the code you want to output in a function in the script and then redirect the output of that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method I found to capture all output from any session is to start a new bash session and tee to a log file. its really useful for tracking more then just a script.

```
bash | tee ~/bash.log #this will save standard output until the bash session is ended
bash 2>&1 | tee ~/bash.log #this will save all output including errors until the bash session is ended
```

or you can just tee the script it's self

`./myscript.sh | tee ./myscript.log #this will log only the output of the script.`

Comment: Your solution addresses STDOUT, but not STDERR

Comment: I put in an example with `2>&1`

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because requirement #1 was "run ./myscript.sh **without additional shell constructs**".

Comment: This question was edited 6 hours ago, I didn't have that information when I first answered the question. It was using `>` output instead of tee and that is why I shared the option for tee.

Comment: @thebtm your answer is wrong. `2>&1` is on the wrong side of the command, it should be on the left hand of the pipe because you want to capture "the error output of the script" not "the error output of the tee command"

Comment: @vdegenne corrected the answer to be a better answer. Thank You

Answer (score 8):

You can always invoke `script` inside a script to log everything.

As to print and log everything at the same time in a bash script to `log.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$SCRIPT" ]
then 
    /usr/bin/script log.txt /bin/bash -c "$0 $*"
    exit 0
fi

echo teste
```

Seeing the log `log.txt`:

```
$ ./a.sh
Script started, output file is log.txt
teste

Script done, output file is log.txt
$ cat log.txt
Script started on Fri Feb 16 17:57:26 2018
command: /bin/bash -c ./a.sh 
teste

Script done on Fri Feb 16 17:57:26 2018
```

Comment: If I understand correctly (some explanations would help :), the script is trying to detect if it's running under `script`, and not re-execute itself. As of Ubuntu 20, it looks like `$SCRIPT` is not set, so the script goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: Good idea to use `script` though, because it allows for interactive terminal output, e.g. Carriage Return, to work. In effect, commands that display single-line progress output (archivers for example), [behave normally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67652/copy-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-log-file-and-leave-them-on-the-console-within-the-sc/164017#comment1100241_164017). As for solving the infinite loop problem, we can [test the shell level](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162839/how-can-a-bash-script-tell-how-it-was-run/474293#474293): `if (( $SHLVL < 3 )); then script...; fi`.

Comment: Also, the arguments of the scripts end up being concatenated and passed in the *code* argument to the shell started by `script` (not `/bin/bash`, that `/bin/bash` argument is ignored with util-linux `script`)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [tee](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html).

Ex:

```
echo "Hello World" | tee out.txt
```

This creates  a file out.txt with the output from the command and prints it to the screen. Use "tee -a filename" if you want to append to the file.

```
echo "Hello" | tee -a out.txt
echo "World" | tee -a out.txt
```

out.txt will have two lines Hello and World (without -a it would only have world)

If you want to save the entire script and output the entire script:

```
./script.sh | tee output.txt
```

Comment: Your solution addresses STDOUT, but not STDERR

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61932/268823  explains how to do STDOUT and STDERR

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because requirement #1 was "run ./myscript.sh **without additional shell constructs**".

Comment: I guess one way to do it would be to put everything into a function, and use tee at the end. That would effectively work as a start and stop capture. And redirecting the STDERR if that is the intention.